# Multiple ablines written in one line in R?

Tags: r

So I want to plot several lines in my plot, which I currently do with the following:

```
abline(1,0)
abline(2,0)
abline(3,0)
abline(4,0)
abline(5,0)
```

But is there a way to write this out without writing 5 lines with abline ? And no, it is no necessarily 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 for the first values, so I don't think looping would do me any good here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For horizontal lines:

```
abline(h=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

For vertical lines

```
abline(v=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: 's solution works for horizontal/vertical ablines. When constant/slope is used instead, 
    abline(a=c(0,1,2), b=c(.5,1,.25)) appears to take the first value in each vector only, i.e. a=0 and b=.5. How can it be forced to iterate?